# how to filter the detected objects in SSD detector?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, tensorflow, real-time, object-detection

I just need to detect the person and ignoring rest objects

how to filter the classes

I tried more time but unfortunately failed

I downloaded mscoco_label_map.pbtxt  from here [enter link description here](http://mscoco_label_map.pbtxt)

and

frozen_inference_graph.pb   from here [enter link description here](https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app/tree/master/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017)

this my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import cv2
import logging
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tqdm import tqdm
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream


class ObjectDetector():
    """
    Base class for object detectors used by the package.
    """
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        # create logger
        self._logger = logging.getLogger('dodo_detector')
        self._logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # create file handler which logs even debug messages
        self._fh = logging.FileHandler('/tmp/dodo_detector.log')
        self._fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # create console handler with a higher log level
        self._ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        self._ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # create formatter and add it to the handlers
        self._formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s - %(name)s]: %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
        self._fh.setFormatter(self._formatter)
        self._ch.setFormatter(self._formatter)
        # add the handlers to the logger
        self._logger.addHandler(self._fh)
        self._logger.addHandler(self._ch)

    @abstractmethod
    def from_image(self, frame):
        """
        Detects objects in an image

        :param frame: a numpy.ndarray containing the image where objects will be detected
        :return: a tuple containing the image, with objects marked by rectangles,
                 and a dictionary listing objects and their locations as `(ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax)`
        """
        pass

    def _detect_from_stream(self, get_frame, stream):
        """
        This internal method detects objects from images retrieved from a stream, given a method that extracts frames from this stream

        :param get_frame: a method that extracts frames from the stream
        :param stream: an object representing a stream of images
        """
        ret, frame = get_frame(stream)

        while ret:
            marked_frame, objects = self.from_image(frame)
            print ((objects))

            cv2.imshow("image", marked_frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
                break  # ESC to quit

            ret, frame = get_frame(stream)

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def from_camera(self, camera_id=0):
        """
        Detects objects in frames from a camera feed

        :param camera_id: the ID of the camera in the system
        """

        def get_frame(stream):
            frame = stream.read()
            ret = True
            return ret, frame

        stream = WebcamVideoStream(src=camera_id)

        stream.start()
        self._detect_from_stream(get_frame, stream)
        stream.stop()

    def from_video(self, filepath):
        """
        Detects objects in frames from a video file

        :param filepath: the path to the video file
        """

        def get_frame(stream):
            ret, frame = stream.read()
            return ret, frame

        stream = cv2.VideoCapture()
        stream.open(filename=filepath)

        self._detect_from_stream(get_frame, stream)




class SingleShotDetector(ObjectDetector):
    """
    Object detector powered by the TensorFlow Object Detection API.

    :param path_to_frozen_graph: path to the frozen inference graph file, a file with a `.pb` extension.
    :param path_to_labels: path to the label map, a text file with the `.pbtxt` extension.
    :param num_classes: number of object classes that will be detected. If None, it will be guessed by the contents of the label map.
    :param confidence: a value between 0 and 1 representing the confidence level the network has in the detection to consider it an actual detection.
    """

    def __init__(self, path_to_frozen_graph, path_to_labels, num_classes=None, confidence=.8):
        super(ObjectDetector, self).__init__()

        if not 0 < confidence <= 1:
            raise ValueError("confidence must be between 0 and 1")

        # load (frozen) tensorflow model into memory
#        path_to_frozen_graph= '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
        self._detection_graph = tf.Graph()
        with self._detection_graph.as_default():
            od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            with tf.gfile.GFile(path_to_frozen_graph, 'rb') as fid:
                serialized_graph = fid.read()
                od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
                tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

        # Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution
        # network predicts 5, we know that this corresponds to airplane.
        # Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a
        # dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine
#        path_to_labels= 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
        label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(path_to_labels)

        # this is a workaround to guess the number of classes by the contents of the label map
        # it may not be perfect
        if num_classes is None:
            label_map_contents = open(path_to_labels, 'r').read()
            num_classes = label_map_contents.count('name:')

        categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=num_classes, use_display_name=True)
        self._category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)
        print self._category_index 
        print ('categories', categories)

        self._categories = {}
#        print self._categories 
#
        self._categories_public = []
        for tmp in categories:
            self._categories[int(tmp['id'])] = tmp['name']
            self._categories_public.append(tmp['name'])

        self._confidence = confidence

        # create a session that will be used until our detector is set on fire by the gc
        self._session = tf.Session(graph=self._detection_graph)

    @property
    def confidence(self):
        return self._confidence

    @property
    def categories(self):
        return self._categories_public

    @confidence.setter
    def confidence(self, value):
        self._confidence = value

    def from_image(self, frame):
        # object recognition begins here
        height, width, z = frame.shape

        image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)
        image_tensor = self._detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
        boxes = self._detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
        # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
        scores = self._detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        classes = self._detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
#        print classes
        num_detections = self._detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

        # Actual detection
        boxes, scores, classes, num_detections = self._session.run([boxes, scores, classes, num_detections], feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

        # count how many scores are above the designated threshold
        worthy_detections = sum(score >= self._confidence for score in scores[0])
        # self._logger.debug('Found ' + str(worthy_detections) + ' objects')

        detected_objects = {}
        # analyze all worthy detections
        for x in range(worthy_detections):

            # capture the class of the detected object
            class_name = self._categories[int(classes[0][x])]

            # get the detection box around the object
            box_objects = boxes[0][x]

            # positions of the box are between 0 and 1, relative to the size of the image
            # we multiply them by the size of the image to get the box location in pixels
            ymin = int(box_objects[0] * height)
            xmin = int(box_objects[1] * width)
            ymax = int(box_objects[2] * height)
            xmax = int(box_objects[3] * width)
#            print ymin

            if class_name not in detected_objects:
                detected_objects[class_name] = []
#                print detected_objects

            detected_objects[class_name].append((ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax))

        # Visualization of the results of a detection.
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            frame,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            self._category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8,
            min_score_thresh=self._confidence
        )

        return frame, detected_objects
def main():
#    SingleShotDetector(self.path_to_frozen_graph, self.path_to_labels)
    SingleShotDetector('frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt').from_camera(0)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

please help me or any suggestions

thank you in advance

Comment: search yourseld, where the list with objects is and how to find the class name for that object. Then remove from.that list all elements that are not of your desired class. Try to understand that code you are using.

Comment: first of all, thank you to your suggestion, I tried more time before writing my post here as mention above, my experience  in detected objects not good, so I write my issue to help